# Parent dialog OnOK() is not getting called on pressing enter key

Tags: mfc

In my  MFC MDI application, I have a modal dialog with CTabctrl. The each  tab page of tabctrl  is loaded with child dialog. When pressing enter key, the OnOK() of parent dialog is not getting called.

How to make it to call onOK() of parent dialog?

Comment: Do you have any multi-line (ES_MULTILINE) Edit controls that have ES_WANTRETURN flag set?

Comment: Could you do a `GetParent()->PostMessage(...)` to simulate clicking the OK button? You have no code or anything so it is hard for anyone to help you.

Comment: This link helped me to resolve my problem.https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/853e439c-1ebd-4bba-b404-d97ce4d4ad62/parent-dialog-onok-is-not-getting-called-on-pressing-enter-key?forum=vcgeneral#853e439c-1ebd-4bba-b404-d97ce4d4ad62